# Bluetooth connections on iOS

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, android-bluetooth, ios-bluetooth

We're trying to observe when Bluetooth devices are connected and disconnected from an iPhone.  We essentially want to react (not necessarily in the foreground) when certain devices of interest connect.  In Android you can receive the [`ACL_CONNECTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED) and [`ACL_DISCONNECTED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html#ACTION_ACL_DISCONNECTED) actions.

What is the equivalent to this behavior on iOS?

I first looked at `CoreBluetooth` before discovering it was for Bluetooth LE, then looked at `ExternalAccessory`, but it only shows MFI devices in [the picker](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/ExternalAccessory/Reference/EAAccessoryManager_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EAAccessoryManager/showBluetoothAccessoryPickerWithNameFilter:completion:) and seems to require users to go through the picker.  The only method we found that would work would be to [go through Apple's `BluetoothManager` itself](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee), which is prohibited as per the [AppStore guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) in section 2.5, presumably so they can have total control over the Apple ecosystem.

---

*Equivalent Android code:*

MyReceiver.java

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

  @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothDevice.ACL_CONNECTED)) {
      //do stuff
    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(BluetoothDevice.ACL_DISCONNECTED)) {
      //do stuff
    }
  }

}
```

AndroidManifext.xml

```
<receiver
  android:name="com.myapp.MyReceiver"
  android:exported="true"
  android:enabled="true"
  android:label="MyReceiver">
  <intent-filters>
      <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
      <action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.ACL_CONNECTED" />
    </intent-filters>
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I [published a demo app called Beetee](https://github.com/michaeldorner/BeeTee) which shows how Bluetooth classic is working on iOS and what the global events are. But this private framework is not AppStore complaint!

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly listen for global events like that in iOS, all apps are in their own sandbox and don't have access to each other.

That said, you could use the `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:` method of the `CBCentralManager` to get a list of devices currently connected.  Calling that function periodically and checking for changes could achieve what you are looking for.